# Which is the best way to get permutations of a bunch of indexes from an df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations, permutation

Which is the best way to get all permutations of a bunch of indexes. We are looking to do this with the intention of running chi squared tests, I might be looking at re-inventing the wheel here. So for the following dataframe

```
 index   value
      a     1.0
      b     2.0
      c     4.0
```

I would want to get the following out

```
group      value
      a,b     3.0
      b,c     6.0
      c,a     5.0
```

Comment: should the value of group `b,c` be `6` instead of `1` , is it a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to import itertools

```
import itertools

In [32]:
indices = [indices[0] + ',' + indices[1] for indices in list(itertools.combinations(df.index , 2))]
indices
Out[32]:
['a,b', 'a,c', 'b,c']


In [31]:
values = [values[0] + values[1] for values in list(itertools.combinations(df.value , 2))]
values
Out[31]:
[3.0, 5.0, 6.0]

In [36]:
pd.DataFrame(data = values , index=indices , columns=['values'])
Out[36]:
   values
a,b  3
a,c  5
b,c  6
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should use combinations from itertools.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> datas = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> list(combinations(datas.keys(), 2))
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b')]
>>> index_combination = combinations(datas.keys(), 2)
>>> for indexes in index_combination:
...  print indexes , sum([datas[index] for index in indexes])
...
('a', 'c') 4
('a', 'b') 3
('c', 'b') 5
```